# Iterating two files at same time, and compare words with strings PYTHON

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to print whenever a word appears on a string, but actually it doesn't print anything.My text files are:

```
words={'apple', 'banana', 'pie'}
strings={'Hello World!', 'I love pie', 'Ate an apple'}
```

`with open("words.txt") as words_file:
        with open("strings.txt") as strings_file:
         all_strings = list(map(str.strip,strings_file))
          for a_string in all_strings:
            for word in words_file:
             if word in a_string:
              print a_string`

and the output would be like

Ate an apple

I love pie

Comment: what *exactly* is the contents of the two files

Comment: hello world!
what's up
I love apple
I ate pie

Comment: this is the exactly content

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip
with open("file1.txt") as f1:
    with open("file2.txt") as f2:
         for f1_line,f2_line in izip(f1,f2): #this will return the same lines from both files
             do_something(f1_line,f2_line)
```

the reason you saw the same thing over and over was that you

```
  for line2 in file2:
      print line1.split() # line 1 will not change until you go through every line in file2
```

[edit] as mentioned in the comments if you are using python2.7+ you can combine the file opening into one line

```
with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2:
         for f1_line,f2_line in izip(f1,f2): #this will return the same lines from both files
             do_something(f1_line,f2_line)
```

the code below may do what you are hoping for ...

```
from itertools import izip
with open("words.txt") as words_file:
    with open("strings.txt") as strings_file:
        all_strings = list(map(str.strip,strings_file))
        for word in words_file:
        for a_string in all_strings:
           if word in a_string:
              print a_string
```

Comment: you can do `with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2:` to knock out another level of indentation

Comment: not in all pythons ... this however is valid for all pythons i think (thats why i put it this way)

Comment: i want to iterate words from file1 inside the lines, yet from the file 1, any tips?

Comment: you still didn't got me, i want to step to another line, only after read ALL words. Going to edit the question

Comment: for completeness: It's supported in Python2.7 and Python3.1+

Comment: it didn't work, in any way, i've been trying to fix it, but i couldn't :(